# Invertir orden de Array Multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito invertir las posiciones de un Array, donde la primera pase a la última la segunda a la penúltima y así sucesivamente.

Por ejemplo, tengo un Array de 3 posiciones:

```
[1,1.00,2300]
[2,1.00,4500]
[3,1.00,2340]
```

y este debería de ser su resultado:

```
[3,1.00,2340]
[2,1.00,4500]
[1,1.00,2300]
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Kevin , Bienvenido al sitio... tiene algún avance en código de lo que intenta lograr ?

Comment: no, soy nuevo en esto :(

Comment: Listo! lo resolví con array.reverse()

Comment: Logré resolver con `Array.reverse();`

Comment: No, reverse no es el indicado para ordenar una columna ... este método cambia las posiciones de los elementos sin tomar en cuenta su valor, Con `sort` debería funcionar .... `array.sort((a,b)=> b[0]- a[0]);` solo tomando en cuenta la primera columna

Comment: Justo lo que ocupo,Quizás no especifiqué bien la pregunta! mi objetivo era cambiar la posición sin importar el valor, simplemente invertir el array... Saludos

Comment: Ah, entonces si. está mal planteada la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Es que de invertir un `array` a ordenador de forma descendente como pones en la pregunta, hay una diferencia...

Comment: @KevinA corrige la pregunta entonces. También desarrolla tu respuesta  para aquellos que vengan detrás puedan entender el código y sabes porque se tiene que aplicar eso y no otro. Échale un vistazo a [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Existen diferentes maneras modificar el orden de un array como `sort()` *(ordena alfabéticamente o numéricamente [[modificandolo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) un poco], ascendente o descendente)*, `reverse()` *(invierte el orden de un array enviando la primera posición a la ultima y así sucesivamente)*, ...

### [REVERSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reverse)

---

**Resumen**

El método `reverse()` coloca al revés (inversamente) una matriz. El primer elemento pasa a ser el último y el último pasa a ser el primero.

---

**Sintaxis**

> arr.reverse()

---

**Descripción**

El método `reverse` cruza los elementos del objeto matriz invocados en su lugar, mutando la matriz, y retornando una referencia a la misma.

---

**Ejemplos**

El siguiente ejemplo crea una matriz  miMatriz, contiene tres elementos, estos son colocados al revés (inversamente) en la matriz.

```js
var miMatriz = [[1,1.00,2300],[2,1.00,4500],[3,1.00,2340]];
var invertida = miMatriz.reverse(); 

console.log(miMatriz); 
console.log(invertida);
```

Comment: Comprendo que quieres poner respuestas más completas... pero citar sin más la documentación de MDN sin ningún tipo de procesamiento o mejora, personalmente no me parece una buena solución. Ni siquiera has adaptado el ejemplo al que se propone en la pregunta, simplemente es un copia-pega inconexo.